# PHP - htmlspecialchars performance and concerns. Alternatives?

Tags: php, performance, htmlspecialchars

I am making a website that is 99% based around user content. I have been reading a lot about security vs xss, csrf, sql injection and all that fun stuff. I understand it all well and have been incorporating proper security. The thing I am concerned about is performance and over usage, looking for a better way.

I understand the idea of accept user input as is. Filter and validate user input before going into database and then output with sanitization with something like htmlspecialchars.

Now here is the thing. Every “entry” a user adds to the database can have around 30 different pieces of information attached to it.

So if they view a page. I would output around 30 htmlspecialchars on that page alone. That seems like over a kill. A listing or search page might have 5 or more variables for each of those items and at 20 listing a page I am easily hitting 100+ uses of htmlspecialchars. That seems insane.

Would this cause a strain on my cheap server? Is there a better way to do it?

My horrible ideas.

(1) How about using strip tags when inputting into the database? I understand the vulnerability of outputting into attributes without htmlspecialchars, but I control where every variable outputs and the worst would be variables going into things like `<h4>$title</h4>` or `<li>$info</li>` never into an href or anything. Wouldn't this save a ton of server usage to have the sanitization done once, instead of on every page load? I could still call htmlspecialchars on a variable if I have to put it inside an attribute.

(2) I understand this a horrible idea. But how about storing the htmlspecialchars sanitized text directly in the database? I know if I ever want to do something else with this data like, make an api, output as json or pdf, I would have to decode htmlspecialchars. But none of those situations are something I would ever do. This seems like it would save a TON of server resources, as I would be sanitizing only once instead of every page load.

(3) Store literal input and htmlspecialchars version sanitized of the text in another column. This way the user still sees their input as it was entered and I only have to htmlspecialchars once on input to the database, instead of every page load. Yes more database storage but otherwise what would be the problems?

Edit: Thanks I now see this is micro optimization.

Comment: Are you actually having performance problems, or just thinking they may occur in the future? I think you may not be giving PHP enough credit.

Comment: Concerned about future, if better way to do it, I would like to do it now.

Comment: I strongly suggest sticking with context-appropriate escaping (i.e. using htmlspecialchars on dynamic data at output time.) If you end up with performance problems in the future, I seriously doubt that it will be because of this.

Comment: If you don't want to allow HTML from the user then just `strip_tags()` before insert.

Answer (score 1):

**My Opinion:** You shouldn't have a big issue with performance. In the future your performance issues will actually decrease since techonology is only enhancing performance regarding the speed of CPU cycles and other factors.

I recommend you keep using the `htmlspecialchars` when echoing out the data. 30 function calls to `htmlspecialchars` is very little work for your server (give your server and php some credit xD) and for the reasons stated above will be even less work in the future.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I was just super worried.

Comment: If you are intrested I created a small benchmark calling htmlspecialcharrs 100k times: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f92c127c4d9d0fcf4ad062ff64a26eb551cf3d7e
took 0.7sec to execute so you should really be fine.

Answer (score -1):

Use http://htmlpurifier.org/, its open source PHP Library used by lot of big forums to clean up user inputs.

you can save the cleaned-up html in your database.